# Can Postman render a file from a base64 string?

Tags: postman

One of my server responses is returning a PDF as a base 64 encoded string.

E.g.

```
{
    "fileName": "my-file.pdf",
    "base64EncodedFileContent": "JVBERi0xLjcKJeLjz9MNCj...
```

Is it possible to render this 64 bit string as a PDF *inside* my Postman collection?

I've looked at decoding the string into an environment variable using `CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse`

I've also looked at https://docs.postman-echo.com/ to perhaps send the bytes back to me with a content type of application/pdf, however it nests any body you send inside a JSON object.

*Note:  This is just a tool of convenience to prevent people using the collection from having to use an external base64 -> PDF converter*

Comment: Maybe this helps?
https://community.postman.com/t/render-pdf-in-visualizer/9193

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to import CryptoJS to decode base64... you could use something like this;

```
const response = pm.response.json().base64EncodedFileContent;
var decodedMessage = atob(response);
console.log(decodedMessage);
```

This might also help with 'vizualising' PDF's in Postman
https://community.postman.com/t/visualize-pdf-on-postman-v8-4-0/23856

Comment: Just watched the video.  Talk about awkward!!!  Awkward or not, it's the only suggested answer to this question after 3 years, so deserves to be marked as correct!  Thanks for sharing!